# CKeditor remove all html tag except div,span on paste event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I want to remove all html tags from CKeditor when user uses Ctrl+v to paste the content.  Following is the code I've written. Not working as I expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    var edits=ev.editor;
    edits.on( 'paste', function(event) {
        var content =  event.data['html'];
        content = $('<div />').html(content).text();
        var $temp=$(content).find('br,p').contents().unwrap().end().end();
        var newtext = $temp.text();
        edits.setData(newtext);
    });
    });
</script>
```

1) I wish to remove all the tags except div,span. But In my code I've to specify which tag to remove. I'm sure there must be some better way to do that
2) Also this code is removing all html tags too. So definitely something is wrong with code

Any better suggestions ??

Comment: Do you mean `strip_tags( $string, '<div> <span>')`?

Comment: Yes, But I was hoping if I could specify which tag should not be strip. And in jquery/javascript only

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://www.php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function strip_tags(html, keepTags) {

    var ptn = new RegExp('<(?!\/?(' + keepTags.join('|') + '))[^>]+>', 'g');
    return html.replace(ptn, '');
}
```

$('').html(content).text() will remove all tags, so just use strip_tags(content,  [ 'div', 'span' ]);

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/tqHLu/1/